# Is a ghoul immune vs roadroach attacks?

Tags: damage, immunities, fallout-the-role-playing-game

Ghouls are immune vs radiation damage and roadroaches deal just that. Does that now mean the ghoul takes NO damage? Or does it mean the ghoul takes damage but the radiation effect does not come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, it still takes physical damage

Radroaches don't deal Radiation type damage directly - their attack deals Physical damage but has a Radioactive damage effect. *Radiation damage* and the *Radioactive damage effect* are related but mechanically distinct things! As the effect describes:

> **Radioactive:** For every Effect rolled, the target also suffers 1 point of radiation damage. This radiation damage is totalled and applied separately, after a character has suffered the normal damage from the attack.

A radroach's bite normally just deals some physical damage. Because the bite is radioactive, it has a chance of *also* dealing some radiation damage, if it happens to get an Effect result on its damage dice - but the above text is clear that this is extra damage which is considered separately from the attack's normal physical damage and only applies after that damage has been dealt. It doesn't convert the normal damage the attack does into radiation damage, so being immune to radiation damage doesn't prevent the physical damage part. (Conversely, even if the creature were somehow immune to physical damage or had so much physical DR that the attack did no normal damage, that would not make them immune to the additional radiation damage.)

The upshot is that a ghoul will still suffer the normal physical damage of a radroach's bite, since they're not immune to physical damage, but their immunity to radiation damage means that they won't suffer any additional harm even if the bite triggers the radioactive effect. You do still need to track the radiation damage, though - ghouls recover 1HP for every 3 radiation damage that would otherwise have been done to them, so the radroach bite might actually heal them!